# Finding duplicate value in array and the gap in them

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Example: [1, 4, 9, 78, 42, 4, 11, 56]
Here the duplicate value is 4 and the gap is 3.

I used the array for each array element but I want this query to be optimized.

Comment: Is this a JS array, or a PHP array? Which one do you intend to use?

Comment: what you have tried post here with what is your input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the following code will do the same for you.

```js
var temp = [1, 4, 9, 78, 42, 4, 11, 56];
var encountered = [];

//This function gets you all the indexes of `val` inside `arr` array.
function getAllIndexes(arr, val) {
  var indexes = [], i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    if (arr[i] === val)
      indexes.push(i);
  return indexes;
}

for(var i=0;i<temp.length;i++) {
    if(encountered[temp[i]]) continue; 
    else {
        var indexes = getAllIndexes(temp, temp[i]);
        encountered[temp[i]] = true;
        if(indexes.length>1) {
            var steps = indexes[1]-indexes[0]-1;
            $('.container').append('Duplicate item: '+temp[i]+' steps: '+ steps+'<br/>');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: When your code runs it gives result Duplicate item: 4 steps: 4, But the steps should 3 as OP has suggested.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi Updated

Answer (score 0):

The below solution will give you if multiple duplicates.

http://jsfiddle.net/saz1d6re - Console Output

http://jsfiddle.net/saz1d6re/2/ - HTML Output

```
var a = [1, 4, 9, 78, 42, 4, 11, 4, 9];

result = [];
verified = [];
for(var i =0; i<a.length; i++){
   b = a[i];
   temp = {};
   temp.value = a[i];
   temp.hasDuplicate = false;
   temp.positions = [];
   temp.differenceFromFirstOccurence = [];
   if(verified.indexOf(b) === -1){
      temp.positions = [i+1];
      for(var j = 0; j <a.length; j++){
        c = a[j];
            if( i !== j && b === c){
         temp.hasDuplicate = true;
         temp.positions.push(j+1);
        }
        }
      verified.push(b);
      result.push(temp);

   }
}

for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
  if(result[i].hasDuplicate){
    firstPosition = result[i]['positions'][0];
    for(var j = result[i]['positions'].length-1; j > 0; j--){
       diff = result[i]['positions'][j] - firstPosition-1;
        result[i].differenceFromFirstOccurence.push(diff);
    }
  }
  result[i].differenceFromFirstOccurence.reverse();
}

console.log(result);

for(var i =0; i < result.length; i++){
    if(result[i].hasDuplicate && result[i].differenceFromFirstOccurence.length){

            console.log("The first occurence of "+result[i].value+" is at "+ result[i].positions[0]);
      for(var j = 1; j < result[i].positions.length; j++){
       console.log("The duplicate occurence of "+result[i].value+" is at "+ result[i].positions[j] +" and difference is "+ result[i].differenceFromFirstOccurence[j-1]);
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach. First map all elements that have duplicates, then filter out empty values.

```
const data = [1, 4, 9, 78, 42, 4, 11, 56];
let duplIndex;

const res = data.map((el, index) => {
duplIndex = data.indexOf(el, index+1);
    if(duplIndex !== -1){
        return {el:el, gap: duplIndex - (index + 1)}
    }
}).filter((el) => {
    return el !== undefined;
});
```